# Centering 2 elements adjacent to each other in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have two elements (map + description inside a box). When on a large screen, both elements appear on the same line, which is good. However, they stay on the left of the page and I would like them to sit in the middle.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbf0dcat/) of the below:

```css
.map {
  float: left padding: 10px;
  width: 410px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.map1 {
  float: right padding: 10px;
  width: 410px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <iframe src="https://ctrc00.carto.com/builder/e2f49f3c-b793-11e6-9ceb-0ef24382571b/embed" width="100%" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
  <p><i>
    <u>Map 1: <strong>12,083 listings</strong> (Sept.2016)</i>
    </u>
    <h4><span style="color: #FFA500;"><strong>Activity:</strong></span></h4>
    <br>
    <strong>183</strong> estimated nights/year
    <br>
    <strong>$127</strong> price/night
    <br>
    <strong>50.2%</strong> estimated occupancy
    <br>
    <strong>$1920</strong> estimated income/month
    <br>
    <h4><span style="color: #FFA500;"><strong>Listing per Host:</strong></span></h4>
    <br>
    <strong>38.2%</strong> multi-listings
    <br>
    <strong>62.0%</strong> single listings
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4><span style="color: #FFA500;"><strong>Room Type:</strong></span></h4>
    <br>
    <strong>55.3%</strong> entire homes/apartment
    <br>
    <strong>42.6%</strong> private rooms
    <br>
    <strong>2.1%</strong> shared rooms
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  <div class="map1">
    <iframe src="https://ctrc00.carto.com/builder/221c9570-b794-11e6-ad89-0e8c56e2ffdb/embed" width="100%" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    <p><i><u>Map 2: <strong>15,640 listings</strong> (Sept.2016)</p></i>
      </u>
      <h4><span style="color: #FFA500;"><span style="color: #FFA500;"><strong>Activity:</strong></span></h4>
      <br>
      <strong>60</strong> estimated nights/year
      <br>
      <strong>$196</strong> price/night
      <br>
      <strong>16.3%</strong> estimated occupancy
      <br>
      <strong>$759</strong> estimated income/month
      <br>
      <br>
      <h4><span style="color: #FFA500;"><strong>Listing per Host:</strong></span></h4>
      <br>
      <strong>28.5%</strong> multi-listings
      <br>
      <strong>71.5%</strong> single listings
      <br>
      <br>
      <h4><span style="color: #FFA500;"><strong>Room Type:</strong></span></h4>
      <br>
      <strong>60.3%</strong> entire homes/apartment
      <br>
      <strong>37.9%</strong> private rooms
      <br>
      <strong>1.8%</strong> shared rooms
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Above and under, I have some simple text/paragraph that are in the middle.

Comment: It took me some time to figure out how to make both maps appear next to each other ^^

Comment: Wrap both blocks in a `div` and use css3 flexbox. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jbf0dcat/2/).

Comment: omg. Was it that simple!!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place your whole html code inside this

```
<div class="container"> </div>
```

and add one class only

```
.container{
   display: flex;justify-content: center;width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="map_airbnb"><iframe src="https://prox.carto.com/builder/4dedf917-eb0c-4121-8c6d-f4ab2a6b75d3/embed" width="100%" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
<strong>Activity:</strong><br><br>
183 estimated nights/year<br>
$127 price/night<br>
50.2% estimated occupancy<br>
$1920 estimated income/month<br><br>
<strong>Listing per Host:</strong><br>
38.2% multi-listings<br>
62.0% single listings <br><br>
<strong>Room Type:</strong><br>
55.3% entire homes/apartment<br>
42.6% private rooms <br>
2.1% shared rooms <br>
</p>
<p class="map_airbnb1"><iframe src="https://prox.carto.com/builder/4dedf917-eb0c-4121-8c6d-f4ab2a6b75d3/embed" width="100%" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
<strong>Activity:</strong><br><br>
60 estimated nights/year<br>
$196 price/night<br>
16.3% estimated occupancy<br>
$759 estimated income/month<br><br>
<strong>Listing per Host:</strong><br>
28.5% multi-listings<br>
71.5% single listings <br><br>
<strong>Room Type:</strong><br>
60.3% entire homes/apartment<br>
37.9% private rooms <br>
1.8% shared rooms <br>
</p>
</div>
```

Put an external div or container to your maps and use justify-content:center

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. Wrap these maps inside a container (in my case `map_holder`).

Have a look at the snippet below (*Use full screen*):

```css
.map_holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="map_holder">
  
<p class="map_airbnb"><iframe src="https://prox.carto.com/builder/4dedf917-eb0c-4121-8c6d-f4ab2a6b75d3/embed" width="100%" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
<strong>Activity:</strong><br><br>
183 estimated nights/year<br>
$127 price/night<br>
50.2% estimated occupancy<br>
$1920 estimated income/month<br><br>
<strong>Listing per Host:</strong><br>
38.2% multi-listings<br>
62.0% single listings <br><br>
<strong>Room Type:</strong><br>
55.3% entire homes/apartment<br>
42.6% private rooms <br>
2.1% shared rooms <br>
</p>
<p class="map_airbnb1"><iframe src="https://prox.carto.com/builder/4dedf917-eb0c-4121-8c6d-f4ab2a6b75d3/embed" width="100%" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
<strong>Activity:</strong><br><br>
60 estimated nights/year<br>
$196 price/night<br>
16.3% estimated occupancy<br>
$759 estimated income/month<br><br>
<strong>Listing per Host:</strong><br>
28.5% multi-listings<br>
71.5% single listings <br><br>
<strong>Room Type:</strong><br>
60.3% entire homes/apartment<br>
37.9% private rooms <br>
1.8% shared rooms <br>
</p>
  
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for that, so just update your css like this:

```
.map_airbnb  {
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
}
.map_airbnb1  {
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .map_airbnb, 
    .map_airbnb1 {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here your original with this update https://jsfiddle.net/9ssukjg4/

Answer (score -1):

> Wrap both blocks in a div and use css3 flexbox. Fiddle. – Muhammad Usman 3 mins ago